# Debug logs not being shownup in developer console

Tags: apex, visualforce, debug

I am having a piece of code in which i am having some debug statements.But in developer console not even single debug is showing up.I even changed the expiration time.

```
 Public PageReference CheckInsurance() {
    system.debug('HELLO:::::');
 if(Insurance1=='Health Insurance'){
   system.debug('HIHIH:::::::'+Insurance1);
 system.debug(Insurance1);
   policy__c Pid=[select id from policy__c where Policy_Name__c='Health Insurance'][0];
    Account a=[Select id from Account where name=:Name][0];
  Agreement__c ag=new Agreement__c(Policy__c=Pid.id,Policy_Holder__c=a.id);
   insert ag; 

  }
        return null;
    }
```

This is the piece of code here the CheckInsurance method is getting invoked through actionfunction & Param tags in VF page.
Pls any suggestions!!

Comment: what's your debug level? it should be a minimum of DEBUG level to see debug statements

Comment: For apex code the debug level its showing debug..Is that what your asking

Answer (score 0):

From [Release note](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_debugging_logging.htm),

> When you open the Developer Console, it sets a DEVELOPER_LOG trace
>   flag to log your activities. USER_DEBUG trace flags cause logging of
>   an individual user’s activities. CLASS_TRACING trace flags override
>   logging levels for Apex classes and triggers, but don’t generate logs.

Make sure that the method `CheckInsurance`() is being called and [you already setted up the debug level](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_debugging_logging_setup.htm)

Comment: Yes it is called and even debug level is setted up

Comment: Which user is calling the class/function? Also make sure that `Show My current Logs Only ` is unchecked and `General Trace Setting for You` are set correctly